# Inverse limit in category of graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $... \leftarrow G_i \leftarrow G_{i+1} \leftarrow ...$ be an inverse system of graphs (which might not  be locally finite), morphisms are symplicial maps (we allow collapsing of edges to vertices).

We define a combinatorial inverse limit as follows:

- vertices are sequences ${x_i}$ such that each $x_i$ is a vertex for $G_i$,
- vertices ${x_i}$ and ${y_i}$ are connected iff for every $i$ we have: $x_i$ and $y_i$ are equal or are connected in $G_i$.

As a set, a combinatorial inverse limit is same as the standard inverse limit of topological spaces, but the topology is different.
In particular, a combinatorial inverse limit of connected graphs might be disconnected.

This construction seems very natural and I wonder if there is anything known about that?

I want to study how Gromov's hyperbolicity behaves when one passes to the inverse limit.
The main example is the inverse limit of graphs of homotopy classes of curves on a surface.

Thus far someone told me about book by Luis Ribes but its main focus is about profinite properties of such limit.
(question was also [asked on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4424443/inverse-limit-in-category-of-graphs) about a month ago, though the only answer was one listed above)

Comment: Here are a couple of references that may be relevant to you. A pro-$p$ curve complex was defined by Wilkes in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02953 . Pro-congruence curve and pants complexes were studied by Boggi: https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04135 .

Comment: Ribes and Zalesski have studied profinite groups acting on profinite graphs and defined profinite trees homologically.